# Metric spaces as schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Récoltes et Semailles, Grothendieck explains he invented the concept of scheme to unify algebraic varieties on algebraically closed fields, arithmetical varieties in characteristic $p$, and also the usual metric spaces. This last part is not obvious to me: if we start with a metric space $(X,d)$ we do have a topological space $X$, but we need a structure sheaf of rings to replace the metric distance $d$ (so that we can distinguish homeomorphic spaces with different metric structure, like a triangle and a circle). The sheaf of continuous functions $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$ seems a natural choice, because distances are $\mathbb{R}$-valued, and because its stalks are local rings. Did Grothendieck have this sheaf in mind to represent metric spaces as schemes? Does this sheaf distinguish homeomorphic spaces with different metric structures?

Comment: I don't think $\mathcal C(X, \mathbb R)$ can distinguish a triangle from a circle. If you have a homeomorphism $f: S^1 \to T$ (where $T$ is a triangle), then any continuous function $T \to \mathbb R$ gives a continuous function $S^1 \to \mathbb R$ by composition, and vice versa. Put differently, the sheaf $\mathcal C(X, \mathbb R)$ knows nothing about the metric, but depends only on the topology.

Comment: @red_trumpet Indeed. Do you see another sheaf to represent the metric structure?